# can gtkextra work with gtk+3

Tags: c, plot, gtk, gtk3

I am developing an application in `glade 3.14.2`. It uses `gtk+ 3`.

I want to plot a graph but `GtkPlot` is deprecated in `gtk+ 3`. I came across `GtkExtra` but it seems it only works with `gtk+ 2`. Is that so? If yes, how can I plot in `gtk+ 3`?

Answer (score 1):

As of now [GtkDataBox](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gtkdatabox/) is the most mature one, although there are plenty of attempts in various stages ([pre-alpha, soon to be beta](https://github.com/drahnr/goatplot), [working concept](https://github.com/chergert/uber-graph), [nice but unmaintained and for gtk2](http://gtkgraph.sourceforge.net/),...) and for various purposes (animated for dynamic data, ...).

A matter of fact, most introduce a dependency on `(lib)gnuplot` in order to get plotting, which in my humble opinion is far from visually pleasing.

---

Reading the source, `GtkExtra` requires `gtk+2.x >= 2.12`. So that is a **No.**

Note that you could do really hacky things like rendering with `gtk+ 2` to an offscreen buffer (via cairo) that `gtk+ 3` renders as yourwidget content for a custom `GtkDrawingArea` derived widget - but I strongly disrecommend doing that, it'd probably be faster to port `GtkPlot` to `gtk+ 3`)

---

Note: For me the autotools setup of `GtkDataBox` did not work and thus I did a quick hack so it uses the [`waf buildsystem`](https://code.google.com/p/waf/) https://github.com/drahnr/gtkdatabox-radioactive